# last.fm GET request timing out meteor

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor, last.fm

I'm currently trying to access last.fm's API using a simple GET request.  The best NPM library I found was last-fm by feross.  The problem is that my request keeps timing out and I don't get any errors.  Is meteor causing this?

My request URL is: 
https://ws.audioscrobbler.com:3000/2.0/?method=artist.getInfo&artist=cher&autocorrect=1&api_key=MY_API_KEY&format=json

Here is the code.

```
import LastFM from 'last-fm';

const lastfm = new LastFM("MY_API_KEY", {userAgent: "buildsmoothie"})

export const ArtistCheck = () => {
  lastfm.artistInfo({ name: "cher" }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    else console.log(data)
  })
}
```

And then I call it in another component here:

```
artistGateCheck(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      ArtistCheck();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed the port :3000 and it works as it should. Used the follow url:

https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getInfo&artist=cher&autocorrect=1&api_key=MY_API_KEY&format=json

Comment: Ah thanks! But do you know why does my local host port show up in the api call?

Comment: Not sure. In the library last-fm by feross, the index.js file have a variable called `const urlBase`, make sure the right url is set as `https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/`

Comment: I'll deploy it tomorrow and see if that stops the problem, thanks for helping me locate it.